# How to find parameters in an equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics

The question is the following:

A new state of matter is described with the following equation of state: $$ PV = AT^3 $$ Where $A$ is a constant. The internal energy $U$ is given by: 
$$ U = BT^n \ln(\frac{V}{V_0}) + f(T) $$
Where $n$, $B$ and $V_0$ are constant.

Find $B$ in function of $A$, and find $n$.

I tried to make use of the fact that entropy is a state-function, of the variables $U$ and $V$, i.e. $$ dS = (\frac{\partial S}{\partial E})_V dE + (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V})_E dV $$

$$ dS = \frac{1}{T}dE + \frac{P}{T}dV $$

I then wrote the differentials $dE$ and $dV$ in the following way:
$$dE = \frac{BT^n}{V}dV $$
$$ dV = \frac{3AT^2}{P}dT $$

I'm stuck with what to do next, can someone please explain?

Comment: Do you see any way to combine those last two equations?

Comment: I substituted the dV of the last equation into the equation above, but couldn't find an answer

Comment: Compute Helmholtz free energy.

Answer (score 0):

The starting point for this should be:

$$dU=C_vdT-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V\right]dV$$

Have you not seen this equation before?